# Vue component: dynamically use router-link or href property

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am generating a menu with the following code:

```
<v-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" link :to="item.to">
    <v-list-item-action>
        <v-icon>{{item.icon}}</v-icon>
    </v-list-item-action>
    <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>{{item.title}}</v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
</v-list-item>

data: () => ({
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Nova Viagem',
                    to: '/viagens/cadastrar',
                    icon: 'fa-route'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lista de Viagens',
                    to: '/viagens/listar',
                    icon: 'fa-list'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Sair',
                    href: '/logout',
                    icon: 'fa-sign-out-alt'
                }
            ]
        })
```

Note that the first 2 items have a `to` property, that is used to generate to `router-link`, but the last item has a `href` property which I want to use to generate a common link (not a vue router link).

How can I dynamically change `:to` to `href` in this line?

```
<v-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" link :to="item.to">
```

Something like

```
item.to ? :to="item.to" : href="item.href" //if item has to, use to, else use href
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `:href` prop is there it should generate a normal link, and if `:to` is there it will render a router link. You should be able to use both `:to` and `:href` in the `v-list-item` without any conditional logic...

```
       <v-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" link 
                :to="item.to" 
                :href="item.href">
                 ...
       </v-list-item>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/ws5MTnaFAF)